# Additional property returned with async:false using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am making a call to a server which returns a JSON encoded object.  This object has to be present before I can continue processing, therefore I am setting async:false in the request which looks like this:

```
    var response = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/test',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data : ({data : requests}),
        success: function(data) {
            response = data;
        }
    });
```

If async: true is set, I get the following object returned:

```
openGeolocationDialog   Object { show=0, data=""}
```

If async: true is set, I get the same object returned, but with an additional 'jQuery...' property:

```
openGeolocationDialog   Object { show=0, jQuery16209069375968417921={...}, data=""}
```

Why is this being returned and how can I suppress it?

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: You wrote `async: true` both times.... which is which? You can always put or call the functions which process the response *inside* the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronous requests are bad from a user point of view: They block the browser.

You should just continue processing in the success callback:

```
$.post('ajax/test', {request: data}, function(response) {
     // continue here
});
```

Take a look at [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), too.

BTW you don't need `dataType: 'json'` if the server returns the proper content-type (i.e. `application/json`).